# CKEditor, how did office html tag got into?

Tags: html, ckeditor, ms-office

I'm managing website that allows user to put some information with CKEditor.

In rare case, when I check in Database, it contains `<o:p>` or `<font>` like below. `<o:p>` tag cuases issue when I convert it back to Word file.

```
<p><font color="#000000" face="Times New Roman" size="3">G</font>
<font size="3"><font color="#000000"><font face="Arial">blahblah. 
<o:p></o:p></font></font></font></p>
```

I did some investigation and o is something to do MS office product.
I tried to replicate by copy content from word/outlook/excel to the webpage but all I get is `<p>` and `<strong>`.

Could anyone help me how my users managed to put `<o:p>` tag? I'm certain that users didn't type that in as they are quiet non technical.

I tried several ways and just couldn't reproduce..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have multiple CKEditor instances with a different config? And one of them have Advanced Content Filter disabled? If you have ACF enabled, such markup will never get into final content (unless it's ofc explicitly allowed) - this is what it was made for.

You can find more about it in [Advanced Content Filter guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter).